# PhoneGap iOS: picture date gives current date

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, ios6

I choose a picture (or video) from the library of the phone, using this:

```js
navigator.camera.getPicture(PictureSuccess, err,{
      allowEdit: false,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
      mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
});
```

Then, after the picture is chosen, I do this in `PictureSuccess(fileURI)` to get to the [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry) and retrieve the file date:

```js
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, function(fileEntry) {

      fileEntry.getMetadata(function(meta){

              console.log(meta.modificationTime);

      }, err);  
}, err);
```

The console output is the current date instead of the the file date on iOS.
On Android phones though, the output is the correct image date. I think iOS modifies the files before giving the picture to my app.

My question is: have you encountered the same problem and did you manage to find a workaround?

(using PhoneGap 2.5.0 and iOS 6.1.2)

Documentation:

- [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry)
- [Metadata](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#Metadata)
- [camera.getPicture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#camera.getPicture)